# MySQL 2 column query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing a booking system (PHP-MySQL) for my hotel rooms.

I got 2 tables

rooms_table

```
----------+---------------+----------------+
room_id   |   room_name   |   room_type    |
----------+---------------+----------------+
125       |   name 2      |    deluxe      |
----------+---------------+----------------+
126       |   name 3      |    deluxe      |
----------+---------------+----------------+
```

rooms_avl_table   ( in which I am saving non-available days for rooms)

```
----------+---------------+----------------+
avl_id    |  room_id      |   navl_date    |
----------+---------------+----------------+
12        |    125        | 2018-10-02     |
----------+---------------+----------------+
13        |    125        | 2018-09-05     |
----------+---------------+----------------+
```

I wanna list all rooms which are not listed in the `rooms_avl_table` table. ie if searching with a date "2018-09-05", needs to show all the rooms with out 126 (room_id) - which is not available.

Comment: And what have you tried???

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select * from rooms_table r
left join rooms_avl a on r.room_id = a.room_id and a.navl_date = '2018-09-05'
where a.room_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `LEFT JOIN` with checking for `NULL` solution by *@isaace*, you can also use a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html) with [NOT IN](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php) clause:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms_table AS rt 
WHERE rt.room_id NOT IN (SELECT rat.room_id 
                         FROM rooms_avt_table AS rat 
                         WHERE rat.room_id = rt.room_id 
                           AND rat.navl_date = '2018-09-05'
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
SELECT * FROM rooms_table AS r
WHERE r.room_id NOT EXISTS (SELECT rv.room_id 
                         FROM rooms_avt_table AS rv
                         WHERE rv.room_id = r.room_id 
                           AND rv.navl_date = '2018-09-05'
                        )
```